# Is there a way to refactor the unpacking of a polymorphic assocation into its model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

**Example:**

Let's say we have a model Reminder with a polymorphic association.

```
class Reminder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rememberable, polymorphic: true
  scope :events, -> { where(rememberable_type: 'Event') }
end
```

I can then get a list of all remembered Events with

```
events = Reminder.events.map(&:rememberable)
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to put this into an extension to the polymorphic association or in a scope of Reminder? So that we can call it like this:

```
events = Reminder.events.unpack
```

**What I tried:**

I tried

```
class Reminder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rememberable, polymorphic: true do
    def unpack
      map(&:rememberable)
    end
  end
  scope :events, -> { where(rememberable_type: 'Event') }
end
```

and

```
class Reminder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rememberable, polymorphic: true
  scope :events, -> { where(rememberable_type: 'Event') }
  scope :unpack, -> { to_a.map(&:rememberable) }
end
```

without success.

**Sidenote:**

I know, it is general bad practice to have a scope end the chainability of ActiveRecord's Relation Proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additionally to breaking ActiveRecord relation chains you are going to have performance issues by using `map` and/or `to_a` which force the fetching of all existing records and looping through them in your Rails process.

So instead of "*Look for existing Reminders and give me the associated Events*" you should "*Find Events that have at least one associated Reminder*". As a matter of fact when designing an association scope you should **always start from the model you expect to have in your results**. Don't try to implement a scope in `Reminder` that would return a collection of `Event`.

1- Let's create a concern:

```
module Rememberable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do |base|
    base.scope :with_reminders, -> { joins :reminders }
  end  
end
```

2- Include that concern to your models

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Rememberable
  ...
```

3- Use it

```
events = Event.with_reminders
```

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite simple. You can use class methods as a scopes in Rails. Therefore let's write class method (in `Reminder`):

```
def self.unpack
  @relation.map(&rememberable)
end
```

or if you prefer scope syntax:

```
scope :unpack, -> { @relation.map(&rememberable) }
```

However due to fact that it ends chainability of ActiveRecord's Relation Proxy I would prefer writing it as a class method (instead of explicit scope).

Comment: I tried to understand your suggestion. May I ask where the `@relation` comes from?

Comment: Scratch that last comment. You answer is correct. That's what I was looking for. Unfortunately Benjamin Sinclaire made me aware that I should not have looked for it, because of some underlying flaws of my design. So I have to give him credit for an even better answer. Sorry.